# Searching for comprehensive textbook

Tags: book-recommendation

I am extremely interested in science in general and in particular biology. Due to a different choice of career-path I probably will not be learning any more biology anytime soon.

So I would love to get my hands on a comprehensive textbook biology which hopefully will enable a goal in lifelong learning of biology.

What are some good recommendations? I looked up biology textbooks on Google and found candidates such as [Campbell Biology](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321831543) by Reece and [Biology](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321831543) by Brooker. But as there are so many of them, I have no clue which one to get.

So, biologists of stackexchange, can you help me out?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SE Biology! A simple search in the SE would have revealed many similar questions! Please look at this link (http://biology.stackexchange.com/search?q=biology+textbook)

Comment: Is the there a specific area of biology you're interested in, or just general?

Answer (score 1):

Try Campbell biology.....it covers almost all the topics under biology in a lucid way...also the book has packed quite a volume of info in it ranging from a beginner level to a fairly advanced level....excellent book also in matters of presentation & writing style so that one won't feel bored....

1. Pros:

   1. Genetics ( both classical and modern)
   2. Ecology (including ethology)
   3. Evolutionary biology
   4. Animal classification
   5. Immunology
2. Cons:

   1. Biochemistry ( it somewhat feels short)
   2. Plant anatomy ( not adequately covered)
   3. Plant classification ( same as above)

& the rest of the chapters are like animal physiology etc. they are mixed...like some 
principles they have gone thoroughly...some others not...but it's acceptable as they have to cover everything in one book...

But of course it's my personal opinion...so before considering it I would rather recommend downloading the book in pdf format & have a look at it yourself...but I feel you won't be disappointed....